# Show that in a UFD, prime elements are irreducible

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification, unique-factorization-domains

> Show that in a UFD, prime elements are irreducible

Here is what I have so far:

Suppose $p \in R$ is prime, then the ideal it generates is a prime ideal in $R$. If $ab$ (where neither $a$ nor $b$ are zero) belongs to $\langle p \rangle$ then we can say (without loss of generality) that $p = ab$, also by by definition $a \in \langle p \rangle$ or $b \in \langle p \rangle$.

Suppose $a \in \langle p \rangle$, then $a = pr$, then $p = prb$ and so $1 = rb$, i.e. $b$ is a unit. Thus since $p$ is equal to a product in which one of the elements is a unit, $p$ is irreducible.

Is this good?

Comment: Sure. Moreover, now you know prime elements are irreducible in any domain, not necessarily UFD.

Comment: yes, of course, but this would work for a UFD since UFD's are domains, correct?

Comment: Yes. However, the fact that you do not need it to be a UFD is important to understand the difference between primes and irreducibles. If you wanted to prove that every irreducible is prime, then you would need unique factorisation.